# Which template is used for receipts sent from admin entry and renewal of memberships?

Tags: civimember, receipts

If I go into CiviCRM and create or renew a membership as opposed to them doing it themselves online, which template is used for the receipt? Specifically I mean if you check the "send confirmation and receipt" box at the bottom of the membership form.

Is it "Memberships - Signup and Renewal Receipts (off-line)?" I think it's the "off-line" part that's throwing me off so I just wanted to confirm. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's this one

Memberships - Signup and Renewal Receipts (off-line)

I often get a bit confused too. Best thing to do if in doubt it to make a minor amendment and do a test. You can easily revert back to the default afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Tony, but no email is being generated for me for a new membership only for a renewal. Very strange!